# Best way of remembering the state of a form with multiple sections

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The app I'm building will have a form screen that could have multiple "TextArea" fields, checkboxes, dropdowns, etc. Here's an example of such a form:

[image: form_mock]

Now I want to somehow remember the state of each field in order to be able to persist it across navigation actions (similarly to `rememberSaveable`) and then convert all the data into a single JSON that I will then send to the backend. It's worth noting that the button at the bottom should only be enabled if every section has data filled, i.e. text area is not empty, at least one checkbox is selected, etc.

What would be the best way to remember all the info while avoiding having a `rememberSaveable` field per component? Should I use a `Form` data class that will hold a `Map<String,String>` for storing dropdown component name & answers for example and similarly for the rest of the sections?

Also, is there any way I can avoid checking if all form sections have data present in order to enable the button, in each and every "onValueChanged" callback?

Here's the screen right now:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RegistrationStep2Screen(
    navController: NavController,
    registrationViewModel: RegistrationViewModel = getViewModel()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(vertical = 40.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        var section1Text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        var selectedDropdownOption by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Answer") }
        val checkboxStates by registrationViewModel.checkboxStates.observeAsState()
        val canProceed by registrationViewModel.canProceedToStep3.observeAsState(false)

        LaunchedEffect(
            key1 = section1Text,
            key2 = checkboxStates!!.values.count { it },
            key3 = selectedDropdownOption
        ) {
            registrationViewModel.canProceedToStep3(
                section1Text,
                checkboxStates!!.values.count { it },
                selectedDropdownOption
            )
        }

        RegistrationProgressBar(currentStep = 2)

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "STEP 2",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_error_color),
                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.montserrat_bold)),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
            Text(
                text = "Please answer the following questions",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
            )
        }


        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
        ) {
            FormSection(
                orderNum = 1,
                title = "Question full text"
            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 10.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .heightIn(min = 111.dp, max = 111.dp),
                    value = section1Text,
                    onValueChange = { value ->
                        section1Text = value.trim()
                    },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                        unfocusedBorderColor = colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_border_color),
                        focusedBorderColor = colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_border_color),
                        errorBorderColor = colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_error_color),
                        errorSupportingTextColor = colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_error_color)
                    ),
                )
            }

            FormSection(
                orderNum = 2,
                title = "Question multiple choice"
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 13.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(40.dp)
                ) {
                    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(11.dp)) {
                        FormCheckBox(
                            onCheckedStatusChange = {
                                registrationViewModel.updateCheckboxState(0 to it)
                            },
                            isCheckedInitVal = checkboxStates!![0]!!,
                            label = "Answer 1"
                        )
                        FormCheckBox(
                            onCheckedStatusChange = { registrationViewModel.updateCheckboxState(1 to it) },
                            isCheckedInitVal = checkboxStates!![1]!!,
                            label = "Answer 2"
                        )
                    }

                    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(11.dp)) {
                        FormCheckBox(
                            onCheckedStatusChange = { registrationViewModel.updateCheckboxState(2 to it) },
                            isCheckedInitVal = checkboxStates!![2]!!,
                            label = "Answer 3"
                        )
                        FormCheckBox(
                            onCheckedStatusChange = { registrationViewModel.updateCheckboxState(3 to it) },
                            isCheckedInitVal = checkboxStates!![3]!!,
                            label = "Answer 4"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            FormSection(
                orderNum = 3,
                title = "Question drop down"
            ) {
                FormDropdownField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    options = listOf("Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3"),
                    defaultOption = selectedDropdownOption
                ) {
                    selectedDropdownOption = it
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))

        if (!canProceed) {
            Text(
                text = "Please complete all fields to proceed to the next step",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_error_color)
            )

            Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))
        }

        FoodakaiButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp),
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.next_step),
            enabled = canProceed,
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Screens.REGISTRATION_STEP3.navRoute)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

FormCheckbox composable:

```
@Composable
fun FormCheckBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: String = "",
    isCheckedInitVal: Boolean = false,
    onCheckedStatusChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    var isChecked by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(isCheckedInitVal) }

    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = modifier
                .width(22.dp)
                .height(22.dp)
                .border(
                    2.dp,
                    colorResource(id = R.color.form_field_border_color),
                    MaterialTheme.shapes.medium
                )
                .padding(1.dp)
                .background(
                    colorResource(id = if (isChecked) R.color.form_checkbox_filled_color else R.color.white),
                    MaterialTheme.shapes.medium
                )
                .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                .clickable {
                    isChecked = !isChecked
                    onCheckedStatusChange(isChecked)
                }
        ) {
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
        Text(
            label,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            fontFamily = FontFamily(listOf(Font(R.font.montserrat_regular)))
        )
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
class RegistrationViewModel(
    private val registrationRepository: RegistrationRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private var _checkboxStates = MutableLiveData(
        mapOf(
            0 to false,
            1 to false,
            2 to false,
            3 to false
        )
    )
    val checkboxStates: LiveData<Map<Int, Boolean>> = _checkboxStates

    private var _userData = MutableLiveData<RegistrationCheckResponse>(null)
    val userData: LiveData<RegistrationCheckResponse>
        get() = _userData

    private var _canProceedToStep3 = MutableLiveData(false)
    val canProceedToStep3: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _canProceedToStep3

    fun updateCheckboxState(state: Pair<Int, Boolean>) {
        val map = _checkboxStates.value?.toMutableMap()
        map?.apply {
            map[state.first] = state.second
            _checkboxStates.value = map.toMap()
        }
    }

    fun canProceedToStep2(email: String, confirmEmail: String) =
        areEmailsMatching(email, confirmEmail) && isEmailValid(email)

    fun areEmailsMatching(email: String, confirmEmail: String) =
        email.trim() == confirmEmail.trim()

    fun isEmailValid(email: String) =
        InputValidator.validateEmail(email)

    fun canProceedToStep3(
        checkboxText: String,
        checkboxCount: Int,
        selectedDropdownValue: String
    ) {
        _canProceedToStep3.value =
            checkboxText.isNotBlank() && checkboxCount > 0 && selectedDropdownValue.isNotEmpty()
    }

    fun verifyByEmail(email: String, onResponse: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (val response = registrationRepository.isRegisteredByEmail(email)) {
                is ResponseResult.Success -> {
                    response.data?.let {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            onResponse(it.isVerified)
                        }
                    }
                }

                is ResponseResult.Error -> {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        onResponse(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun verifyByRegistrationId(regId: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (val response = registrationRepository.isRegisteredById(regId)) {
                is ResponseResult.Success -> {
                    response.data?.let {
                        _userData.postValue(it)
                    }
                }

                is ResponseResult.Error -> {
                    println(response.exception.message)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun resendVerificationEmail() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = _userData.value?.id?.let {
                registrationRepository.resendVerificationRequest(it)
            }

            when (response) {
                is ResponseResult.Success -> {
                    println("SUCCESS")
                }

                is ResponseResult.Error -> {
                    println("Exception: ${response.exception.message}")
                }

                else -> {
                    println("UNKNOWN ERROR")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun verifyUser(onSuccess: () -> Unit, onFailure: () -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (val response = _userData.value?.id?.let {
                registrationRepository.verifyUser(it)
            }) {
                is ResponseResult.Success -> {
                    onSuccess()
                }

                else -> {
                    onFailure()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Before posting here I actually tried using a single Form data class like I mentioned and updating it with each component's callback but it doesn't seem to actually remember the state even though it was being stored in the viewModel and observed through LiveData using observeAsState.

Comment: Few suggestions, storing all the values in viewmodel is preferable. And in viewmodel for states use MutableStateFlow instead of liveData. If you can share your full UI code which creates this screen completely, I can update your viewmodel to show how ideally these should be handled in compose including button enabling case

Comment: Asking for opinion is not allowed on SO. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper way except for using Jetpack Room library. I was stuck with similar problem (remembering state for future reuse for backend) and realized that I should be able to restore the program state even after relaunch. Yes, using Room sounds like overhead, but this is the only way. You may also use shared prefs or datastore, but if you want to implement highly structured forms you should save the data in the highly structured way.